# Hibernate + JUnit Multithreaded Integrated Test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I used Hibernate together with Spring in JUnit to do an integration. I am use multiple reads and writes to test my codes if they handled the concurrency correctly. The thing with Hibernate is I can't use multiple thread alone to simulate that. Hibernate complained there is no active Hibernate Session bound to DAOs. So, what I did to get that working was to execute the DAOs' methods inside a Hibernate's TransactionTemplate in a Thread e.g.

```
   Thread alpha = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TransactionTemplate tt = new TransactionTemplate(tm);
                tt.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
                    @Override
                    public void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                        Address address =addrDao.findBy("John Doe");
                        address.setZipCode("12345");
                        addrDao.update(address);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

Create another thread, beta, with the same content with an additional time delay. Finally, start both threads,

```
    alpha.start();
    beta.start();
```

It  worked. My question, is there any better way to do this other than using TransactionTemplate(...) in an Spring+Hibernate+Junit setup?

Also, I found that the action cannot be rolled back at the end of this test even though I have included **`@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)`** at the beginning of this test case.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

trueAdd the following to you test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:application-context.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)
```

and the following line to your application-context.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

You can remove the explicit transaction handling in your test code.

Comment: Yes, I added all that in my test class. These works only if your test is single thread.

Comment: defaultRollback=true is by default. Annotation `@TransactionConfiguration` is enough